# Django Import Posts from other blogs

Tags: python, django, blogs

I would like to make an application which will import posts from other blogs, such as CNN, WSJ, BBC etc. Do you know if there is any already developed module to do this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You might want to look at http://code.google.com/p/django-reader/

Answer (score 2):

You can use [FeedParser](http://code.google.com/p/feedparser/) to do that.

Answer (score 1):

django-feedreader may help you.
https://bitbucket.org/tghw/django-feedreader

Also feedjack. 
http://www.feedjack.org/